# Format time greater than 24 hours

Tags: c#, asp.net, timespan

I have a textbox were the user can enter in the estimate hours, for example it could be 150 hours. How do I format this time? The time automatically formats to `00:00:00` so If I enter in 150 hours it changes to `34.22:59:59`

```
TimeSpan tmpEstimate;
TimeSpan? TimeEstimate;

if (TimeSpan.TryParse(txtEstimateHrs.Text, out tmpEstimate))
    TimeEstimate = tmpEstimate;
else
   TimeEstimate = null;
```

The user will only enter in the hours so I don't need to format the minutes or seconds but the field could also be left blank so it needs to accept a null time to

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's better to use `double` value for input, not `time`?

```
TimeSpan? TimeEstimate = null;
double tmpEstimate; 
if (double.TryParse(txtEstimateHrs.Text, out tmpEstimate)) 
{ 
    TimeEstimate = TimeSpan.FromHours(tmpEstimate); 
}
```

OR

```
double? TimeEstimate = null;
double tmpEstimate; 
if (double.TryParse(txtEstimateHrs.Text, out tmpEstimate)) 
{ 
    TimeEstimate = tmpEstimate; 
}
```

Comment: More complete: `double tmpEstimate;
if (double.TryParse(txtEstimateHrs.Text, out tmpEstimate))
{ TimeEstimate = TimeSpan.FromHours(tmpEstimate);
}
else
{ TimeEstimate = null;
}` Blank text field will go to the `else` branch as desired.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thank you, fell free to edit answers. at least, my :)

Comment: TimeEstimate is still formatting the hours. If I enter in 150 TimeEstimate changes the 150 to `6.06:00:00`

Comment: @user123456789 For that, use `TimeEstimate?.TotalHours`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I'm not sure what you mean with `TimeEstimate?.TotalHours`... I cannot say `TimeEstimate.TotalHours` it gives an error. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen if I change the line to this `TimeEstimate = TimeSpan.FromHours(tmpEstimate).TotalHours; `it causes the error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'System.TimeSpan?'

Comment: @user123456789 let's use `double` instead of `TimeSpan` at all!

Comment: @user123456789 But exactly where do you see the representation `6.06:00:00`? Internally, the `TimeSpan` is a signed 64-bit integer counting a number of "ticks". As soon as you see `6.06:00:00`, an implicit or explicit call to `ToString` has taken place somewhere. Your goal is to figure out where, and change that `.ToString()` into `.TotalHours.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in the hours then take a look at `TimeSpan.FromHours()`, which takes a number of hours and makes you a TimeSpan object for that value only.
If the value is null then you can handle that separately.